# PIVOT Table from soft configured fields with ID Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

I have some dynamnic form fields that are stored in the database as config with values saved against them in a separate table and I want to create a view that provides a PIVOT table turning the FieldName value into columns that are then grouped by the ID.

SO the following table:

```
ID  |  FieldName      |  FieldValue
1      An Integer        10
1      A String          Hello
1      A boolean         True
2      An Integer        20
2      A String          Goodbye
2      A Date            01/01/2010
```

Will output as:

```
ID    |  [An Integer]    |  [A String]   |  [A boolean]   |  [A Date]
1        10                 Hello           True             Null
2        20                 Goodbye         NULL             01/01/2010
```

There may be more column names than this and Im ok with the dynamic side of it, but assuming the table above is fixed, how do I achieve the PIVOT?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and pivot features are highly DBMS specific). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
PIVOT (
  MAX(FieldValue)
  FOR FieldName in (
    'An Integer', 'A String', 'A boolean', 'A Date'
  )
)
```

In your example you don't specify how the result should be aggregated. So I just used max. The grouping is done with the pivot so there is no need for an extra group by or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are dealing with a fixed list of field names, you could just use conditional aggregation. This is a cross-RDBMS solution that does not depend on vendor-specific implementations of `PIVOT`, and usually performs as well or better:

```
select 
    ID,
    max(case when FieldName = 'An Integer' then FieldValue end) an_integer,
    max(case when FieldName = 'A String' then FieldValue end) a_string,
    max(case when FieldName = 'A Boolean' then FieldValue end) a_boolean,
    max(case when FieldName = 'A Date' then FieldValue end) a_date
from mytable
group by ID
```